# Check validity of std::function before calling?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to program a simple but flexible event system (mostly just as an exercise, I know there are existing libraries that have really good event handlers), and I've run into a little stumbling block.

How can you check if an `std::function` that's a delegate (probably through a lambda, possibly though std::bind) is a valid function/if the object for the member function still exists before calling it? I've tried simply using `std::function's` bool operator, but haven't had any success.

Ideally I'd like to A. do the checking somewhere other than inside the delegate function, and B. still have the code be valid when the std::function that's being checked isn't a delegate.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Here's the source for the test that I ran

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class Obj {
public:
    std::string foo;
    Obj(std::string foo) : foo(foo) {}
    std::function<void()> getDelegate() {
        auto callback = [this]() {this->delegatedFn();};
        return callback;
    }
    void delegatedFn() {
        std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Obj* obj = new Obj("bar");
    std::function<void()> callback = obj->getDelegate();
    callback();
    delete obj;

    //perform some type of check here whether function is valid, without needing to know whether the function is a delegate or not
    if(callback) {
        std::cout << "Callback is valid" << std::endl; //callback is still considered valid after obj is deleted
        callback(); //no exception thrown, prints a random series of characters
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Callback is invalid" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried? Preferably as a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also include any errors you get.

Comment: It isn't possible to check if some random pointer still points to a valid object, and your use case reduces to the same thing.

Comment: After seeing your example code I would say that this is really no different from other stray pointers variants, like if the `Obj` class had a function that returned a pointer to the member variable `foo` and you tried to use it after `obj` was deleted. The only thing possible is to keep track of it yourself, there's no "magic" the library or compiler can do to help you here.

Comment: Most probably you have AB problem. What you asked probably can be implemented, but it would be over-complicated. Better describe why you need it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use smart pointers (`std::shared_ptr`/`std::weak_ptr`) instead of naked ones:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class Obj {
public:
    std::string foo;
    Obj(std::string foo) : foo(foo) {}
    void delegatedFn() {
        std::cout << foo << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    auto obj = std::make_shared<Obj>("bar");
    std::weak_ptr<Obj> ptr = obj;
    std::function<void()> callback = [ptr](){
        auto sh = ptr.lock();
        if(sh) { std::cout << "valid" << std::endl; sh->delegatedFn(); }
        else { std::cout << "invalid" << std::endl; }
    };
    callback();
    obj = nullptr;
    callback(); 
    return 0;
}
```

In this case you are not directly checking the *validity* of a `std::function` (that is valid when you assign it something, even if that *something* captures a dangling pointer).
Instead, you check that the referred object is still alive from within the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

The broadcaster/listener pattern I use looks like this:

```
template<class...Args>
struct broadcaster {
  std::vector< std::weak_ptr< std::function<void(Args...)> > > callbacks;

  void operator()(Args...args) const {
    std::remove_erase_if( begin(callbacks), end(callbacks), [](auto&& ptr){return !ptr;} );
    auto tmp = callbacks;
    for (auto pf : tmp) {
      if (pf && *pf) (*pf)(args...);
    }
  }
  std::shared_ptr<void> listen( std::shared_ptr<std::function<void(Args...)>> f ) {
    callbacks.push_back(f);
    return f;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<void> listen( std::function<void(Args...)> f ) {
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<std::function<void(Args...)>>(std::move(f));
    return listen(ptr);
  }
};
```

Listeners to a message `.listen` their callback with `broadcaster`.  They get back a `shared_ptr<void>` token.

So long as that token exists, the broadcaster will send messages at the function object passed in.

`Obj` would either store a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<void>> tokens` or a single `std::shared_ptr<void>`.  When it was destroyed, its listeners would automatically deregister.

Alternatively, `Obj` could inherit from `shared_from_this`.  Then it implements

```
std::function<void()> delegate;
std::shared_ptr<std::function<void()>> getDelegatedFn() {
  if (!delegate) delegate = [this]{ this->delegateFn(); }
  return {
    &delegate,
    shared_from_this()
  };
}
```

which shares the lifetime of the `Obj` instance itself (uses the aliasing constructor of `shared_ptr`).  Pass this to `listen` and done.